# Duplicate rows of a 2d array to represent each date within the start and end date values of the row

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, range, repeat

I have the following array called $exhibitions:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Picasso
            [venue_name] => Gallery 1
            [room_name] => Room 4
            [start_date] => 2023-11-15
            [end_date] => 2023-12-10
            [room_id] => 261
            [exhibition_id] => 3540
            [venue_order] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Monet
            [venue_name] => Gallery 4
            [room_name] => Room 2
            [start_date] => 2023-10-01
            [end_date] => 2023-11-13
            [room_id] => 274
            [exhibition_id] => 8417
            [venue_order] => 1
        )
)
```

What I need to do is use the `start_date` and `end_date` to create a range of dates each exhibition is open, and then for each of those dates essentially duplicate the rest of the information in the existing sub-array with the individual date appended to the end of the sub-array. My desired output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Picasso
            [venue_name] => Gallery 1
            [room_name] => Room 4
            [start_date] => 2023-11-15
            [end_date] => 2023-12-10
            [room_id] => 261
            [exhibition_id] => 3540
            [venue_order] => 2
            [date] => 2023-11-15
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Picasso
            [venue_name] => Gallery 1
            [room_name] => Room 4
            [start_date] => 2023-11-15
            [end_date] => 2023-12-10
            [room_id] => 261
            [exhibition_id] => 3540
            [venue_order] => 2
            [date] => 2023-11-16
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Picasso
            [venue_name] => Gallery 1
            [room_name] => Room 4
            [start_date] => 2023-11-15
            [end_date] => 2023-12-10
            [room_id] => 261
            [exhibition_id] => 3540
            [venue_order] => 2
            [date] => 2023-11-17
        )
    [... etc. for the rest of the dates in the Picasso date range]

    [25] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Monet
            [venue_name] => Gallery 4
            [room_name] => Room 2
            [start_date] => 2023-10-01
            [end_date] => 2023-11-13
            [room_id] => 274
            [exhibition_id] => 8417
            [venue_order] => 1
            [date] => 2023-10-01
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Monet
            [venue_name] => Gallery 4
            [room_name] => Room 2
            [start_date] => 2023-10-01
            [end_date] => 2023-11-13
            [room_id] => 274
            [exhibition_id] => 8417
            [venue_order] => 1
            [date] => 2023-10-02
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [exhibition_title] => Monet
            [venue_name] => Gallery 4
            [room_name] => Room 2
            [start_date] => 2023-10-01
            [end_date] => 2023-11-13
            [room_id] => 274
            [exhibition_id] => 8417
            [venue_order] => 1
            [date] => 2023-10-03
        )
    [... etc. for the rest of the dates in the Monet date range]
)
```

I saw [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925989/php-collect-dates-between-2-dates-and-create-entry-for-each) and modified it so that instead of echoing the `$given_date`, it added it to the array in a new column called "date".

```
foreach ($exhibitions as $key => $value) {

    $startDate = strtotime($value['start_date']);
    $endDate = strtotime($value['end_date']);

    // Loop between timestamps, 24 hours at a time
    for ($i = $startDate; $i <= $endDate; $i = $i + 86400 ) {
            $given_date = date('Y-m-d', $i );     
            $exhibitions[$key]['date'] = $given_date;
    }    

};
```

The problem was that instead of adding one date per date in the date range, it added the last date in the range only. When I echoed the `$given_date` just to make sure it was iterating each date, it lists every date in the range, so I'm assuming there's something wrong with how I added the new column but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Iterate your input array's rows and access the start and end dates.
- Create an iterable payload of dates using PHP's native DateTime methods.
- Loop over those dates, append the individual date to the row data, then pass the extended row into the result array.

To have an "inclusive" range of dates, add 1 day to the end date (otherwise every range will be one day short).

By appending the generated date to the row data with the union operator (`+`), you avoid needing to write out every element in the row while pushing.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2IQhp))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($exhibitions as $row) {
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($row['start_date']),
        new DateInterval('P1D'),  // 1 day per step
        new DateTime("{$row['end_date']} +1 day")  // +1 day to include end date
    );
    foreach ($dateRange as $d) {
        $result[] = $row + ['date' => $d->format("Y-m-d")];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

...from PHP8.2, you can use a special flag instead of `+1 day`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/crkGA))

```
$dateRange = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($row['start_date']),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime($row['end_date']),
    DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code. You are overwriting the **'date'** key in each iteration of the loop, so only the last date is stored in the original array. I have rewrite the code for you, please have a look, hope it will solve you issue.

```
<?php

$exhibitions = array(
    array(
        'exhibition_title' => 'Picasso',
        'venue_name' => 'Gallery 1',
        'room_name' => 'Room 4',
        'start_date' => '2023-11-15',
        'end_date' => '2023-12-10',
        'room_id' => 261,
        'exhibition_id' => 3540,
        'venue_order' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'exhibition_title' => 'Monet',
        'venue_name' => 'Gallery 4',
        'room_name' => 'Room 2',
        'start_date' => '2023-10-01',
        'end_date' => '2023-11-13',
        'room_id' => 274,
        'exhibition_id' => 8417,
        'venue_order' => 1,
    )
);

$result = array();

foreach ($exhibitions as $key => $value) {
    $startDate = strtotime($value['start_date']);
    $endDate = strtotime($value['end_date']);

    // Loop between timestamps, 24 hours at a time
    for ($i = $startDate; $i <= $endDate; $i = $i + 86400) {
        $given_date = date('Y-m-d', $i);

        // Create a new array for each date and append it to the result array
        $result[] = array(
            'exhibition_title' => $value['exhibition_title'],
            'venue_name' => $value['venue_name'],
            'room_name' => $value['room_name'],
            'start_date' => $value['start_date'],
            'end_date' => $value['end_date'],
            'room_id' => $value['room_id'],
            'exhibition_id' => $value['exhibition_id'],
            'venue_order' => $value['venue_order'],
            'date' => $given_date,
        );
    }
}

// $result now contains the desired output
print_r($result);

?>
```

You can check the output on this link https://onecompiler.com/php/3ztkkmvw9

Comment: Using the magic number `86400` is not recommended generally and when daylight saving may be involved may cause corrupted results.